# why does not update the database and returns this error?

Tags: laravel

ERROR: Property [encomendas] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Code:

```
 $update = encomendas::join('encomendas', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_encomenda', '=', 'encomendas.id')
        ->join('users', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR);

    $update->estado = 2;

    $update->save();
```

I thank anyone who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this:

```
$update = encomendas::join('encomendas', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_encomenda', '=', 'encomendas.id')
        ->join('users', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR);
```

returns a `Builder` instance, not a `Model/Collection`. If you need the results, you have to `->get()` them, or if you only need to update them, you can just do:

```
$update = encomendas::join('encomendas', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_encomenda', '=', 'encomendas.id')
        ->join('users', 'encomendas_detalhes.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
        ->update(['estado' => 2]);
```

Comment: gives it  back this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'encomendas' but if i remove the ->update(['encomendas.estado' => 2]) or ->update(['estado' => 2]) stay ok no error with database

Comment: @MicaPereira you need to rename the table, give me some minutes

Comment: @MicaPereira are you sure about the first join? what is `encomendas_detalhes`?? the table of the Model `encomendas`?

Comment: @MicaPereira this problem is on your query, and it's a totally different problem of the one you are talking on the question, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198108/eloquent-join-table-on-itself

Comment: detalhes id  details

Comment: i sold thw problem

Comment: I had a table that I didn't need but thanks for calling attention to the tables, it was a bad option to copy past another controller

Comment: $update = encomendas::
        join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
        ->update(['encomendas.estado' => 2]);